# SDL2 y la memoria de video

Tags: c++

Encontré que `SDL_Texture` guarda en la memoria de video, pero tengo un problema me esta guardando las imágenes como búfer en la RAM 
ademas tengo problemas con la optimización una imagen de 0,2mb ( en los recursos ) termina pesando 2,5mb al importarla con `IMG_Load` y `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`.

Comment: No veo nada en la documentación de `SDL_Texture` indicando que se guarde en la memoria de video, ¿qué documentación estás consultando?. Respecto al tamaño de imagen: la mayoría de formatos de imagen contienen compresión, pero cuando almacenas la imagen en memoria ésta se almacena sin compresión.